# g++ cant compile 32 bit with mudflap

Tags: g++, 32-bit

I have a project that for the time being has to be compiled in 32 bit mode.  I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 -64 bit and it works fine with the -m32 switch.
Now I wanted to debug with the -fmudflap option, but I get a series of undefined functions (__real_malloc, __real_calloc, __real_free, etc.).
I tested with a trivial hello world program and it works fine in a 64bit compile, but not in 32bit mode.
Is there a different library to link besides -lmudflap ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install the 32-bit version of mudflap.

Comment: How specifically can I do that?  I didn't see a 32 version of mudflap in package manager.

Comment: I did some digging and did an 'sudo apt-get install lib32mudflap0'.  That seems to have done the job.  Weird that before this install, I didn't get any sort of error suggesting the wrong library was being loaded.